# What is "thematic" about this keypad code?

Tags: plot-explanation, safe-tv

In episode 7 in the TV series [Safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_(TV_series)) Tom and Pete visit a bar called "Heaven" and observe a staff member entering the code `8-4-8-5-8-6` (or `84-85-86`) into a keypad.

Tom then says "How very thematic."

What is thematic about this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heaven is a 1980's themed bar.  So a code of 84-85-86 sounds like 3 years in the middle of the 1980s.